# Argument 'ProductListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why I'm getting this error? I'm using AngularJS 1.3.15

app.js file:

```
(function () { 
  'use strict';
   var app = angular.module('productManagement', ['common.services']);
}());
```

productListCtrl.js file:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
.module('productManagement')     
.controller('productListCtrl', ['productResource', productListCtrl]);

function productListCtrl(productResource) {
    var vm = this;
    productResource.query(function (data) {
        vm.prodcts = data;
        console.log(vm.prodcts);
        //alert(vm.prodcts);
    });
}
}());
```

productListView.html file

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="ProductListCtrl as vm">
<div class="panel-heading">Product List</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Code</td>
                <td>Available</td>
                <td>Price</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="product in vm.products">
                <td>{{product.productId}}</td>
                <td>{{product.productCode}}</td>
                <td>{{product.releaseDate | date}}</td>
                <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

and my index.html file link:
http://pastebin.com/vwaLPyUH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your controller as `productListCtrl` but using `ProductListCtrl` thus your are getting the error.

Use

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="productListCtrl as vm">
```

instead of

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="ProductListCtrl as vm">
```

Comment: Yes my error has gone, now there is no errors. Thanks! `console.log(vm.prodcts);` is logging data too. But I can see any data on browser. Any clue please?

Comment: @Towhid, Same  issue defined `prodcts` and using `products`

Comment: Thanks Satpal! Now its working fine. I think these typos are going to kill me.